# Biggest set such that sum of any pair is perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the biggest set of positive integers such that the sum of any pair of them is a perfect square? (Or can we construct an infinite such set?)

One such set of size $3$ is $\{6,19,30\}$, which give sums $25,36,49$, but I can't find any larger yet.

Comment: It seems that a secondary requirement is that no element of the set is to be added to itself...

Comment: I changed your wording a bit. My tired brain had to read your question three times before it made any sense of it; hope it is less ambiguous now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to do. The formula below. It is only necessary to take $a,b,c$.

You can even for 4 terms to write.

Do there exist four distinct integers such that the sum of any two of them is a perfect square?  This is equivalent to solving the following system of equations:  $$\left\{\begin{aligned}& b+a=x^2 \\&b+c=y^2\\&b+f=z^2\\&a+c=e^2\\&a+f=j^2\\&c+f=p^2\end{aligned}\right.$$  Let: $F,T,R,D$ - any asked us integers.  For ease of calculation, let's make a replacement.  $$q=(8F^2+4FT-T^2)R^2+2(T+2F)RD-D^2$$  $$k=(8F^2+8FT+2T^2)R^2+2(T+2F)RD$$  $$s=-T^2R^2+2(T+2F)RD-D^2$$  $$t=(8F^2+12TF+3T^2)R^2+2(T+2F)DR-D^2$$  Then the solutions are of the form:  $$x=s^2+k^2-t^2+2(t-k-s)q$$  $$y=t^2+k^2-s^2+2ks-2tk$$  $$z=s^2+k^2-t^2$$  $$e=t^2+k^2+s^2-2kt-2ts$$  $$j=t^2+s^2-k^2+2ks-2ts$$  $$p=3s^2+3k^2+3t^2-6kt-6st+8ks+2(t-k-s)q$$  $$b=\frac{x^2+y^2-e^2}{2}$$  $$a=\frac{e^2+x^2-y^2}{2}$$  $$c=\frac{e^2+y^2-x^2}{2}$$  $$f=\frac{2z^2+e^2-x^2-y^2}{2}$$

Comment: I do not find this enlightening. Where did all these equations come from? Without some explanation, and an argument that the method you use will generalize to an $n$-set, it does not answer the original question, which asks how big the original set can be.

Comment: @MJD I said. $$\left\{\begin{aligned}&a+b=x^2\\&a+c=y^2\\&b+c=z^2\end{aligned}\right.$$ Solution: $a=\frac{y^2+x^2-z^2}{2}$ ; $b=\frac{z^2+x^2-y^2}{2}$ ; $c=\frac{z^2+y^2-x^2}{2}$ . I think. I understand everything explained.

Comment: You have six diophantine equations in four unknowns. How do you know there is a solution?  What is $q$ and why did you introduce it?

Comment: @MJD $F,T,R,D$ - integers which we ask. All other numbers are derived from them.

Comment: I think I can catch a glimmer at how this was arrived at (but don't have the time to work it all out): First, the sets of three are indeed easy to obtain: They are the set $\{a,b,c\}$ given by any $x$, $y$, $e$ at the end of the answer – just so long as the parities are chosen so that $a$, $b$, $c$ are integers. I'll consider next a quadruple $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ with $a_i+a_j=b_{ij}^2$ when $i\ne j$. The $b_{ij}$ must clearly satisfy $b_{12}^2+b_{34}^2=b_{13}^2+b_{24}^2$ plus the same with all permutations of $1234$ – which suggests the rewrite (to be continued …)

Comment: … $(b_{12}-b_{13})(b_{12}+b_{13})=(b_{24}-b_{34})(b_{24}+b_{34})$ … and I keep being reminded of the standard way to parametrize Pythagorean triples. But now other obligations require my attention, sorry … (@MJD)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen  This is not an easy task as it seems. This task is even Euler solved. The discussion can be viewed there.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=602478  I brought his vision of the solution to this problem.  Euler came to the necessity of solving algebraic equations, 4-th degree. Although it is necessary in the General case. To solve a system of two Diophantine equations of degree 2.

Comment: Ah, that link explains how you could post the answer within 7 minutes of the question being posted. And no, I didn't think it would be at all easy; but even so, it does seem that I underestimated the difficulty. (So it seems both of us disagree with your opening statement “It's easy to do”.)