# generalization of Euler's challenge of finding four integers every pair of which sum to a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am not a mathematician, but I was reading about Euler’s challenge to find four integers every pair of which summed to a perfect square, and I found myself wondering whether it was the case that, for every *n*, and every *k*, there was a set of *n* integers such that every pair in the set summed to a perfect *k*th-power, and, even more generally, whether it was the case that, for every *n*, every *m*, and every *k*, there was a set of *n* integers such that every *m*-tuple in the set summed to a perfect *k*th-power. (And if there is such a set, does it follow that there are infinitely many such sets?) Answers will have to be accessible to a non-mathematician! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks to Harald Helfgott for encouraging me to post the question.

Comment: Seems very unlikely. If I had it handy, I'd look in Richard Guy's book, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory. See if you can find it at a university library.

Comment: It would be astonishing if even the first proposition were true.  Take for example $n=4$.  If every pair in a set of 4 integers summed to a $k$th power, by pairing the 4 integers in two different ways we could obtain a solution to the Diophantine equation $a^k+b^k=c^k+d^k$.  In fact, however, despite extensive searching (see the entries for Diophantine equations to various powers in [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/DiophantineEquations.html)), it seems that no solutions are know for $k\geq5$.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. How about if we restrict the powers to squares, as in Euler's example? Do we know whether, for every _n_, there is a set of _n_ integers such that every pair in the set sums to a perfect square?

Comment: You might get some joy out of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952801/biggest-set-such-that-sum-of-any-pair-is-perfect-square

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks very much for that link.

Comment: I have read the linked page, @GerryMyerson, and it was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allan J. MacLeod, On sets of integers where each pair sums to a square.

We discuss the problem of finding distinct integer sets $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$  where each sum $x_i+x_j$, $i\ne j$, is a square, and $n\le7$. We confirm minimal results of Lagrange and Nicolas for $n=5$ and for the related problem with triples. We provide new solution sets for $n=6$ to add to the single known set. This provides new information for problem D15 in Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*.

https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1666

See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408301/size-of-set-of-integers-with-all-sums-of-two-distinct-elements-giving-squares

Comment: Thanks. I look forward to going through these.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the linked page, and it is very helpful.

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" my answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Thanks very much, @GerryMyerson!